# Limit of function of function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a function $H(t)$. I have another sequence $t_1, t_2, .., t_k$ with $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}{t_k} = -\infty$.

Very intuitively, I think we could write $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} H(t_k) = \lim \limits_{t \to -\infty} H(t)$ but I can't prove it rigorously.

Could you please suggest me a way to prove the above statement ? Thank you very much!

Comment: $H$ must be *continuous*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If $H$ is continous, could you please suggest me some way to prove the statement ? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are you assuming that the limit $t \to \infty$ exists?

Comment: That's the definition of continuity.

Comment: @copper.hat: yes, the limit $t \to \infty$ exists :)

Comment: Then the result follows from the definition of $\lim_{t \to \infty} H(t)$.

Comment: @copper.hat: sorry, could you provide a sketch of the proof if it does not take you for too long ? I just can't understand the relationship of  the definition of $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} H(t_k)$ with the definition of continuity. Moreover, $t \to - \infty$ instead of $+\infty$ in this case

Comment: Suppose the limit is $L$. The definition says that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $T$ such that if $t > T$ then $|H(t)-L| < \epsilon$. Now you just need to show that there is some $K$ such that if $k \ge K$ then $t_k > T$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks for your kind response. But it seems to me the definition you gave is the definition of a sequence rather than the definition of limit of a function (which should involve $\epsilon - \delta$ I think). Am I right ?

Comment: The definition I gave is a fairly standard one for $\lim_{t \to \infty}$.

Comment: What @copper.hat said is fine. Note that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_{n})=f(c)$ for every sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ that converges to $c$ (and you can regard diverging sequences as ``converging" to $\pm\infty$ if necessary)